# How to find branch whose commit have been merged or rebased

Tags: git, merge

Git makes it really easy to find merged branch with `git branch --merged`.

Some projects like to rebase feature branches and I'd like to find, with git tools, whether my feature branch has been integrated or not (either merged or rebased).

> Is it possible to find if the patch of a given commit (or branch) is present in the current branch ?

Note: if you consider answering on the merge vs. rebase topic: please don't.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to find if the patch of a given commit (or branch) is present in the current branch ?

Yes, if you know your `SHA-1` you can use `git show <SHA-1>` and it will print out the first occurrence of the given commit or message

you can alos pass to git show the name or any part of your branch name to search for it as well.

---

## More search options

#### git show :/

```
git show :/"any search string"
```

Search and display the **first** commit with the matching string.

More info: [git-show](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show)

#### git log grep

```
git log --grep="Message"
```

Very similar to the previous git show but this time it will display **all** the matches and not only the first match

---

#### Here are few examples for the different options:

`git log`

[image]
`git show :/"Merge"`

[image]

`git log --oneline --decorate --grep="Merge"`
[image]

Comment: I think that the SHA-1 will change when you rebase, so this wouldn't work

Comment: SHA-1 will certenly change when you rebase so you need to use`git show :/"..."` in this case

Comment: as mentionned in other comments, my point is to find if the patch (the diff) is in the history (not the commit). Thanks for git show :/ , I 'll make a sript around that